# Is it possible to shorten this code?

Tags: java, joptionpane

I'm not exactly a beginner in Java, but I'm also not an expert. Is there any way to shorten this code so that it takes up less space and possibly fewer lines?

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The student's names are: " 
  + roster[0][0] + " " + roster[1][0] + ", " 
  + roster[0][1] + " " + roster[1][1] + ", " 
  + roster[0][2] + " " + roster[1][2] + ", and " 
  + roster[0][3] + " " + roster[1][3] + ".");
```

Comment: This is asking for a loop there...

Comment: Yeah but if I put a loop, it'll repeat the entire statement multiple times...

Comment: Use a `for` loop from `0` to `3` and construct the string using `roster[0][i]` and `roster[1][i]`

Comment: Yes but I only want one message box. That will make it so that I will need to make multiple.

Comment: Then construct the string in a loop, and _then_ call `JOptionPane#showMessageDialog` using your constructed string.

Comment: I suggest that you look into using `StringBuilder` if you decide to use a loop. It will make for much more efficiency.

Comment: You could use two embedded loops to create the message that contains the array values but with the loops and the multiple if statements to handle the formatting, you will finish with more line code.
But it could  be more robust if you change the array size, particularly if it grows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String rosterString = "";
for(int i = 0; i < roster[0].length; i++) {
    rosterString += roster[0][i] + " " + roster[1][i] + ", ";
}
```

That code will create a string with the names and commas.  You could then add in if statements to check if it is near the end to change the `,` to an `and` or `.`

Comment: Oh btw String is uppercase :D (and there should be a ; before the })

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!  And thanks for pointing out the flaws so I could fix them.

Answer (score 3):

### Let's refactoring the code step by step

1. introduce variables to remove duplication.

   ```
   T[] col1 = roster[0];
   T[] col2 = roster[1];

   String content = col1[0] + " " + col2[0] + ", "
           + col1[1] + " " + col2[1] + ", "
           + col1[2] + " " + col2[2] + ", and "
           + col1[3] + " " + col2[3] + ".";

   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The student's names are: " + content);
   ```
2. separate string concatenation into multi-assignments, then all assignments are the same except the last one.

   ```
   int i = 0;
   String content = "";
   content += col1[i] + " " + col2[i] + ", ";i++;
   content += col1[i] + " " + col2[i] + ", ";i++;
   content += col1[i] + " " + col2[i] + ", ";i++;
   content += "and " + col1[i] + " " + col2[i] + ".";i++;
   ```
3. make the multi-assignments consistent by using ternary operator.

   ```
   int i = 0;
   String content = "";
   content+= (i==3?"and ":"") + col1[i]+" "+col2[i] + (i==3?".":", "); i++;
   content+= (i==3?"and ":"") + col1[i]+" "+col2[i] + (i==3?".":", "); i++;
   content+= (i==3?"and ":"") + col1[i]+" "+col2[i] + (i==3?".":", "); i++;
   content+= (i==3?"and ":"") + col1[i]+" "+col2[i] + (i==3?".":", "); i++;
   ```
4. using while-loop to remove duplication.

   ```
   int i = 0;
   String content = "";
   while(i<=3) {
       content+= (i==3?"and ":"") + col1[i]+" "+col2[i] + (i==3?".":", "); 
       i++;
   }
   ```
5. replacing while-loop with for-loop.

   ```
   String content = "";
   for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
       content+= (i==3?"and ":"") + col1[i]+" "+col2[i] + (i==3?".":", ");
   }
   ```
6. introduce variables to make the code more readable.

   ```
   String content = "";
   for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
       String prefix = i == 3 ? "and " : "";
       String current = col1[i] + " " + col2[i];
       String suffix = i == 3 ? "." : ", ";
       content += prefix + current + suffix;
   }
   ```
7. inline the variables `col1` & `col2` that is used only once:

   ```
   String content = "";
   for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
       String prefix = i == 3 ? "and " : "";
       String current = roster[0][i] + " " + roster[1][i];
       String suffix = i == 3 ? "." : ", ";
       content += prefix + current + suffix;
   }
   ```
8. replace magic number `3` with constant and the final code is below:

   ```
   final int last = 3;
   String content = "";
   for (int i = 0; i <= last; i++) {
       String prefix = i == last ? "and " : "";
       String suffix = i == last ? "." : ", ";
       String current = roster[0][i] + " " + roster[1][i];
       content += prefix + current + suffix;
   }

   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The student's names are: " + content);
   ```

Comment: Good job, very didactic!

Answer (score 2):

```
StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder("The student's names are: ");
for (int i = 0; i < roster[0].length; i++) {
    message
        .append(roster[0][i])
        .append(" ")
        .append(roster[1][i]);
    if (i < roster[0].length - 1)
        message.append(", ");
    if (i == roster[0].length - 2)
        message.append("and ")
}
message.append(".");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message.toString());
```

Possibly something like that. As you can see, you don't really save any lines, but obviously the code is more flexible as it can account for a variable length roster.

Comment: "it can account for a variable length roster." By using `roster[0]` and `roster[1]`, I have some doubts. I have not downvoted.

Comment: OP has shown that his data structure is a bit goofy and would appear to have the structure of `roster[0]` containing firstnames, with `roster[1]` containing lastnames. So the "length" of the roster as I see it is the number of firstname/lastname pairs in the array, which this can account for. A more intuitive approach would certainly be to use `roster[i][0]` and `roster[i][1]` for first/last name respectively, but that's not what was provided.

Comment: I'm assuming roster[0] is first names and roster[1] is last names

Comment: Indeed but it tomorrow, the birthday is added as a third index value, this way of doing doesn't work. "it can account for a variable length roster." was not required as it is misleading.

Comment: It certainly does continue to work if the birthdates are stuck in `roster[2]` which would be a likely assumption, it just doesn't show them. There is literally no way to write this code such that it can intelligently display a totally unknown data structure. Adding a loop to print the values at `roster[i][j]` would not produce particularly nice output, since you'd most likely want different separating characters.

Comment: then he can add one more line to append the birthday onto the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following: Initially assign the normal statement that you do not want repeated. Then loop through roster.

```
String rosterString= "The student's names are: ";
for(int i=0;i<= roster.length;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<= roster[i].length;j++){
         rosterString += (roster[i][j] + " ");
         if (i == 1 && j < 2) {
             rosterString += ", ";
         }
         else if (i == 1 && j == 2) {
             rosterString += ", and";
         }
         else if (i == 1 && j == 3) {
             rosterString += ".";
         }
         else {
             rosterString += " ";
         }
    }
}
```

And then pass `rosterString` to your method.